Why didnt Prahlada ji leave Sanda and Amarka?
Why didnt Prahlad ji leave Sanda and Amarka when they taught against Vishnu?

Sanda and Amarka were the brahmana teachers entrusted by Sukracharya, the Guru of Hiranyakashipu and taught knowledge which entails the duality of worldly affairs i.e., Dharma (religion), Artha (economic development) and Kama (sense gratification).
Prahladji did not have a need to externally reject them because as a pure devotee of Lord Vishnu, he was situated in non-dual consciousness and could thus perceive the supersoul in every living and non-living entity, including his materialistic teachers.
The supreme position of Prahladji can be understood by his below words spoken to Sanda and Amarka as per Bhagavata Purana 7.5:
श्रीप्रह्राद उवाच पर: स्वश्चेत्यसद्ग्राह: पुंसां यन्मायया कृत: ।
विमोहितधियां द‍ृष्टस्तस्मै भगवते नम: ॥ ११ ॥


Prahlāda Mahārāja replied: Let me offer my respectful obeisances unto
the Supreme Personality of Godhead, whose external energy has created
the distinctions of “my friend” and “my enemy” by deluding the
intelligence of men. Indeed, I am now actually experiencing this,
although I have previously heard of it from authoritative sources.

स यदानुव्रत: पुंसां पशुबुद्धिर्विभिद्यते । अन्य एष तथान्योऽहमिति
भेदगतासती ॥ १२ ॥


When the Supreme Personality of Godhead is pleased with the living
entity because of his devotional service, one becomes a paṇḍita and
does not make distinctions between enemies, friends and himself.
Intelligently, he then thinks, “Every one of us is an eternal servant
of God, and therefore we are not different from one another.”

स एष आत्मा स्वपरेत्यबुद्धिभि- र्दुरत्ययानुक्रमणो निरूप्यते । मुह्यन्ति
यद्वर्त्मनि वेदवादिनो ब्रह्मादयो ह्येष भिनत्ति मे मतिम् ॥ १३ ॥


Persons who always think in terms of “enemy” and “friend” are unable
to ascertain the Supersoul within themselves. Not to speak of them,
even such exalted persons as Lord Brahmā, who are fully conversant
with the Vedic literature, are sometimes bewildered in following the
principles of devotional service. The same Supreme Personality of
Godhead who has created this situation has certainly given me the
intelligence to take the side of your so-called enemy.

यथा भ्राम्यत्ययो ब्रह्मन् स्वयमाकर्षसन्निधौ । तथा मे भिद्यते
चेतश्चक्रपाणेर्यद‍ृच्छया ॥ १४ ॥


O brāhmaṇas [teachers], as iron attracted by a magnetic stone moves
automatically toward the magnet, my consciousness, having been changed
by His will, is attracted by Lord Viṣṇu, who carries a disc in His
hand. Thus I have no independence.

